# How to fix "java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found." error in Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

There are 2 entities: Deck and Card. Each Deck contains 8 out of 100 possible Cards. Since each Deck contains more than one Card and the Card can also be part of many different Decks, I joined them by creating a new table called deck_cards.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "cards")
public class Card {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    private String icon;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
                },
                mappedBy = "cards")
    private Set<Deck> decks;
// setters and getters
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="decks")
public class Deck {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
                })
    @JoinTable(name = "deck_cards",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "deck_id", 
referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "card_id", 
referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Card> cards = new HashSet<>();
// setters and getters
}

@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DeckRepositoryImpl implements DeckRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Deck getDeckContaining(List<String> cardIds) {
        String queryStr =
                "select deck_id\n" +
                "from deck_cards\n" +
                // Hard-coding card_ids of interest for now to 
                // see if the query itself works
                "where card_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)\n" +
                "group by deck_id\n" +
                "having count(*) = 8";
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryStr, 
Deck.class);
    return (Deck) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

I have a custom-defined method named getDeckContaining(), which was originally designed to take in List cardIds and see if there's a deck containing the ids stored in the list. For now, I hard-coded the ids of cards to look for in the query string. Even then, when I invoke the method like this:

```
    List<String> teamCardIdsInString = new ArrayList<>();
    //....
    Deck deckOfInterest = 
    deckRepository.getDeckContaining(teamCardIdsInString);
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
2019-07-29 19:00:06.663  WARN 3409 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2019-07-29 19:00:06.664 ERROR 3409 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'id' not found.
2019-07-29 19:00:06.690 ERROR 3409 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [select deck_id
from deck_cards
where card_id in (26000060, 28000017, 26000044, 26000039, 26000027, 28000015, 26000033, 28000000)
group by deck_id
having count(*) = 8]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:561) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getInt(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at
```

I am confused since I thought I used the field names as defined in the entities. Is there something that I might have missed?

Comment: so you have "decks" table in your DB? you didn't specify any "@Table" annotation before "Deck" class so JPA will look for "Deck" table by default

Comment: Oops I forgot to add the part where I specified table name when I copy pasted the code. It existed as @Data@Entity@Table(name="decks") but still couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

*java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.* The issue is with the name of the column.
`referencedColumnName = "id"` is the possible suspect here (below)

Possible Solution:

- Remove `referencedColumnName = "id"`
- As you haven't posted name as per your DB scheme (and also there is no `@Column`) make sure that id field in your DB exist

Comment: what's the problem with having the same id column name for both entities?

Comment: Hello @mangusta, In our last project someone has created the columns with the same name and for relationship mapping, we have to be precise to which entity we are referring. In my view, it's good to have a name with an associated entity such as deckId isn't it?

Comment: it doesn't make any difference, joinColumns and inverseJoinColumns refer to different tables so jpa knows which table "referencedColumnName" belongs to

Comment: the only possible cause that I see here is that either of "cards" or "decks" does not have id column (probably both)

Comment: It might be the case or name may be different in db